# Exception thrown at 0x793F3729 (vcruntime140d.dll) in filePath.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, linked-list, stack

I'm attempting to implement a linked list as a stack so I created on a custom class for it in C++. 
Below is what I used to push the temp1 variable into the stack. My current issue is when I push into the stack, it throws an exception.

```
cityNode temp1(dest, cost + dataVector[index].cost, time + dataVector[index].time);
stack->pushCity(temp1);
```

This is the node.

```
class cityNode {
    public:
        string name;                        // City name
        double totalCost;                   // Total cost of the flight
        int totalTime;                      // Total time of the flight
        cityNode* destCity;                 // Pointer to the next destionation city

        cityNode(string cityName, double cityCost, int cityTime) {
            name = cityName;
            totalCost = cityCost;
            totalTime = cityTime;
            destCity = nullptr;
        }
};
```

Below is my code. The exception is currently thrown when it reaches the `newCity->totalCost = cityNode.totalCost;` part of the code.

```
class CityStack {
    public:
        class cityNode* top = NULL;
        void pushCity(cityNode cityNode) {
            class cityNode* newCity = (class cityNode*) malloc(sizeof(class cityNode));
            newCity->name = cityNode.name;
            newCity->totalCost = cityNode.totalCost;            // Exception Thrown
            newCity->totalTime = cityNode.totalTime;
            newCity->destCity = top;
            top = newCity;
        }

        void popCity() {
            if (top == NULL) {
                cout << "Stack Underflow" << endl;
            }
            else {
                top = top->destCity;
            }
        }

        bool emptyCity() {
            if (top == NULL)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        void reverseCity() {
            cityNode *prev, *cur, *succ;
            cur = prev = top;
            //cur = cur->destCity;
            while (cur != NULL) {
                cityNode *temp = cur->destCity;
                delete cur;
                cur = temp;
            }

            //prev->destCity = NULL;
            while (prev != NULL) {
                cityNode *temp = prev->destCity;
                delete prev;
                prev = temp;
            }

            while (cur != NULL) {
                succ = cur->destCity;
                cur->destCity = prev;
                prev = cur;
                cur = succ;
            }
            top = prev;
        }

        void displayCities() {
            cityNode *stack = top;
            while (stack != NULL) {
                cout << stack->name << " ";
                stack = stack->destCity;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

        cityNode* getCityNode() {
            return top;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0xcdcdcdcd` is used by Visual Studio to mark uninitialized heap memory; you read such uninialized memory and thus get this invalid pointer. You should be using `new`, not `malloc` in C++:

```
void pushCity(cityNode cn) {
  cityNode* newCity = new cityNode(cn.name, cn.totalCost, cn.totalTime);
  newCity->destCity = top;
  top = newCity;
}
```

`new` will allocate the correct amount of memory, and will invoke your constructor appropriately. Meanwhile, `malloc` will just allocate a bit of memory in the correct size, but do nothing to initialize the object. This leads to [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Comment: When I did this it gives me this results: ```identifier "newCity" is undefined```

Comment: @ThuVu Don't make the parameter name the same as the class name. I'll edit the code with a complete fix

Comment: @ThuVu Try the code as written; it should work now that the name of the parameter isn't conflicting with the name of the class

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `malloc` in a C++ program (unless you really know what you are doing) because it doesn't call the constructors for the objects you are creating.

Replace this

```
class cityNode* newCity = (class cityNode*) malloc(sizeof(class cityNode));
```

with this

```
cityNode* newCity = new cityNode;
```

Answer (score 1):

as others have mentioned use new instead
but if you insist on allocating memory with malloc for any reason (for example avoiding exception when new can't allocate memory for anyreason like not enouth memory)

you need to call constructor explicitly  by "replacement new"

```
   class cityNode* newCity = (class cityNode*) malloc(sizeof(class cityNode));
   if(newCity ==0)
    {throw("can't allocate memory");}
    new(newCity)  cityNode();
    ...
    //you need to call destructor expilictly too
    newCity.~cityNode();
    //you still must use free() not delete
    free(newCity);
```